# Handling very big Matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have data-set of epinions website and want to implement the recommendation system
At the first step I should change the structure of data-set an it should be like `120000*780000 rows and columns`
Its really big matrix and because of lack of memory it's not possible to do it
In my work every user should have M-dimensional vector , And *M* is total number of items that is `780000`
I cant use sparse matrix because I need indexes and its too slow
What can I do now? How can I have this big data-set in matlab ?

Comment: I don't think using a sparse should be *that* slow, by itself. Are you sure your matrix is actually *sparse*? And are you preallocating?

Answer (score 0):

You can try different things to reduce the amount of data:

1. Take a random subset of your observations: 120.000 observations is quite a lot, try randomly splitting it in several smaller subsets and check which is the performance of the system.
2. Use PCA to reduce the dimensionality of your data: 780.000 dimensions is A LOT. You will probably get a drastic reduction of the number of dimensions with PCA.
3. If your data is mostly zero or constant, you can actually use sparse matrices. Sparse matrices keep track of the indexes of your non-zero data, so don't worry about that.